# ERRO DE EXECUCAO ODBC_EXEC PHP

Tags: php, odbc

Fala pessoal,
estou passando a seguinte situação, tenho uma consulta cujo resultado passo para um while, e dentro do while eu faço um INSERT no banco. Porém notei que o INSERT esta duplicando no BD. Já fiz vários testes, tenho a impressão do problema ser no ODBC_EXEC mas não desvendei até o momento.

Consulta:

```php
$QUERY     = "  SELECT FR027_NUMERO,FR027_ITEM,FR027_IDSOLICI
                FROM FR00027 
                WHERE FR027_NUMERO = '$NUMERO' ";
$RESULT    = odbc_exec($conexao, $QUERY);
```

While:

```php
while ($ARRAY = odbc_fetch_array($RESULT)) {
  $NUMERO     = $ARRAY['FR027_NUMERO'];
  $ITEM       = $ARRAY['FR027_ITEM'];
  $IDSOLI     = $ARRAY['FR027_IDSOLICI'];

  $QUERYIN    = "  INSERT INTO FR00026 (FR026_COTACAO,FR026_ITEM,FR026_SOLICI,FR026_CODFORNECE,FR026_DESCFORNECE,FR026_CIDADE,FR026_FONE,FR026_EMAIL,FR026_DTCAD,FR026_USRCAD)
                   VALUES      ('$NUMERO','$ITEM','$IDSOLI','$CODFOR','$DESCFOR','$CIDADE','$FONE','$EMAIL','$DTCAD','$USRCAD')";

  echo $QUERYIN . "<br />";
  $RESULTIN   = odbc_exec($conexao5, $QUERYIN);
  odbc_free_result($RESULTIN);
}
```

Como podem ver, estou imprimindo o INSERT para teste, e está ok, porém os registros duplicam no BD.

Answer (score -2):

Achei o problema, existia um modal de exibicao de imagem, o qual era preenchido via javascript, o atributo src="#" estava assim, ja que seu preenchimento era via javascript, removi o mesmo e o codigo funcionou como esperado.